# How to switch to another geometry node within animation?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, instances

I am trying to make an animation where there are a bunch of people and they all swivel towards the center of the plane that they are standing on.

As far as I can tell, I would have to remake the whole geometry node and that seems impossible so it would be possible with just switching to another geometry node.

The people are points on the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keyframe (<kbd>`I`</kbd> key) the *Switch* choosing a node, or you can keyframe the visibility of the entire Geometry Nodes modifier. Normally Geometry Nodes are animated by animating inputs to various functions, often based on the *Scene Time* node, but since you asked about *"switching to another geometry node"*, I think this is more relevant:

[image]